iperf shows gig speed but scp does not
OS is Debian 12 on both servers.
On server A:
iperf -s

On server B:
iperf -c server-a

Result is 940 Mb/s
Trying to copy a file via scp from server B to server A:
scp test.img server-a:/mnt/test

The result is 45 MB/s. Not terrible, but also not ideal. Same result with rsync.
Read speed of the drive on server B seems fine:
dd if=test.img of=/dev/null bs=1M iflag=direct status=progress

Result is 400 MB/s without caching.
Write speed of the drive on server A seems fine too:
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1M count=4000 oflag=direct status=progress 

Result is 200 MB/s even without caching.
I have no other traffic on my network. I can run the iperf test over and over and get the same result.
I would expect to see the file copied over at 117.5 MB/s.
How do I get the full speed from my gig network?

Check your units.  Mb/sec (megabits/sec) is a different measure from MB/sec (megabytes/sec).

It's worth noting that many modern machines would absolutely not be limited by the encryption in a Gigabit ethernet scenario. Check yourself – scp something from localhost, or just
ssh -oCompression=no localhost cat /dev/zero | pv > /dev/null

my 12 year old PC does roughly 400 MB/s that way, my newer laptop is even faster, but both do only maybe 40 MB/s over scp from localhost. Encryption is not the bottleneck here. So, do not sacrifice security or privacy to this!
The bottleneck is simply the inefficient way that scp uses the network link, and that's partially due to SSH, and partially due to the fact the both your network interface and your storage system have "transfer chunkiness", which interacts in inelegant ways. Now, the chunkiness of your localhost SSH connection is 32 kB, and the roundtrip time for TCP acknowledgements is basically zero, but there's still protocol roundtrips "atop" of that, and, also important, for every read from storage giving you data, there's a context switch, and for every packet SSH sends via TCP there's another one. (In fact you'll see a read, a write syscall, and a ppoll every 2 of these, and a rt_sigprocmask or similar call, because there's elegant non-blocking waits and thread synchronization to be done. Your ssh client does a lot of syscalls! That eats time, and its CPU cycles. Usually, on a system running a heavily used SSH connection, more than the cryptography.)
So, first step first: make sure you have jumbo frames on your NIC activated. From the throughput you do achieve, I'd assume that's already the case, but doesn't hurt to check your MTU is not set to 1500 on your Gigabit Ethernet interface.
Then, consider whether other encrypted protocols than SFTP (which I'm sure your scp program is actually using, and not the original SCP, which is really terrible in terms of performance) might be the way to go. I haven't benchmarked this for straightforward file transfer myself, but I've seen NFS via Wireguard over 250 Mb/s cable internet work quite well (no idea of speed, though), so that might be an interesting option; SMB can work fully encrypted as well.
As a first test: netcat/ncat (probably the latter) can be a nice benchmark, because it's "so darn simple"; server-side:
ncat --send-only -p 9999 < /path/to/image/file

client:
ncat --recv-only server-ip 9999 | pv > /dev/null

Then, set up a wireguard connection between your two hosts and compare speeds when you use the wireguard IP instead of server-ip. Compare using the wireguard interface to using ncat --send-only --ssl -p 9998 on the server and ncat --recv-only --ssl server-ip 9998 on the client.
Note that this is doesn't do authentication (other than that wireguard will only allow the peer with the right public key to connect, but any program on that peer could send you arbitrary data).
